# Individual input box won't resize without others resizing as well

Tags: html, css, input, resize

Pretty straightforward. I'm trying to resize individual input boxes, but when I try to resize them (using classes) it resizes every box. Not sure what is wrong. Here's the code:

```css
    /* Centre the page */
    .body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 450px;
      top: 50px;
      background-color: #444;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    /* Centre the form within the page */
    form {
      margin:0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style the text boxes */

    input, textarea {
      height:30px;
      background:#444;
      border:1px solid white;
      padding:10px;
      font-size:1.4em;
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
      border:1px solid white;
      color: white;
    }

    #submit {
      height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

      #submit:hover {
      background-color:#005f5f ;
    }

    .info {
      size: 175px;
    }

    .message {
      size: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <form method="post" action="../php/index.php">
        
      <input class="info" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
            
      <input class="info" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
            
      <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="How can I help?"></textarea>
            
      <input class="info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        
  </form>
 </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know the code is messy, I've been trying everything so I haven't had time to clean it up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`size` is not a precise method for sizing your html input [according to the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT).
I would recommend using eg: `width: 10em` or `width: 20px` to size the width of your input.

For CSS, you could use the name attributes to specify the element you want to have with a different width.

```
.info[name='email'] {
  width: 12em;
}

.info[name='name'] {
  width: 13em;
}

<input class="info" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">            
<input class="info" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
```

Having different `class name` for the different elements also works.

```
.info-long {
  width: 130px;
}

.info-short {
  width: 100px;
}

<input class="info-long" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">            
<input class="info-short" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
```

Run the snippets below for an example for different width input form.

```css
/* Centre the page */
    .body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 450px;
      top: 50px;
      background-color: #444;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    /* Centre the form within the page */
    form {
      margin:0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style the text boxes */

    input, textarea {
      height:30px;
      background:#444;
      border:1px solid white;
      padding:10px;
      font-size:1.4em;
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
      border:1px solid white;
      color: white;
    }

    #submit {
      height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

      #submit:hover {
      background-color:#005f5f ;
    }

    .info[name="name"] {
      width: 13em;
    }

    .info[name='email'] {
      width: 12em;
    }

    .message {
      width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <form method="post" action="../php/index.php">
        
      <input class="info" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
            
      <input class="info" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
            
      <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="How can I help?"></textarea>
            
      <input class="info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        
  </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class for all your inputs are the same ie. info. All inputs that have the same class will get the same styles.So, your resizing will apply to all of them. Give a different class to the input you want to resize or prefrebly give an id and then resize it using CSS. Since info has only the width specified inside it other aspects  won't change.